# Is Bigquery slow when doing joins on range?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table researchers of size ~ 200K rows and another table requests of ~ 50K rows. I am issuing the following request.

```
SELECT a._id, a.createdAt, b.time, b.researcherId FROM
datasci.requests as a 
JOIN analytics.researchers as b on
ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(a.createdAt, b.time , MINUTE)) < 15
```

I'd assume that this would finish in about couple of minutes - a merge through 2 lists after sorting them. But the request is taking > 1 hour in Bigquery, and hasn't completed yet. I retried it couple of times, and same outcome. Does this query need to be rewritten?

One option is to "help" BQ by adding an extra ON condition like
    WEEK(a.createdAt) == WEEK(b.time) 
Does that help or make it only worse?

Answer (score 2):

OK. Answering my own question. So, empirically it helps adding an equality condition along with the inequality condition (orders of magnitude faster). However, in my specific case I added the following condition

```
ON (DATE_SUB(DATE(a.createdAt),INTERVAL 1 DAY)  = DATE(b.time)) OR (DATE_ADD(DATE(a.createdAt),INTERVAL 1 DAY)  = DATE(b.time))  OR (DATE(a.createdAt  = DATE(b.time)) AND ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(a.createdAt, b.time , MINUTE)) < 15
```

That took too much time. So, I split it into 3 separate queries and unioned them which worked

```
ON (DATE_SUB(DATE(a.createdAt),INTERVAL 1 DAY)  = DATE(b.time)) AND ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(a.createdAt, b.time , MINUTE)) < 15

ON (DATE_ADD(DATE(a.createdAt),INTERVAL 1 DAY)  = DATE(b.time)) AND ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(a.createdAt, b.time , MINUTE)) < 15

ON (DATE(a.createdAt  = DATE(b.time)) AND ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(a.createdAt, b.time , MINUTE)) < 15
```

This only took a few seconds.

Comment: BigQuery doesn't yet support efficient spatial joins, as you've observed. It ends up being modeled like a CROSS JOIN with a filter instead, which isn't as fast. If this type of analysis is important to you, you could consider filing a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/) to encourage the BigQuery team to prioritize it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Elliott has mentioned in his comment - `It ends up being modeled like a CROSS JOIN with a filter instead, which isn't as fast`
So, in addition to `filter` being not fast by itself - I think that you are also unreasonably overcharging this `filter` by putting `all calculations` inside it - I would just transform your query into below - where at least some (or most calculation) `expenses` are moved back to pre-join phase

```
SELECT a._id, a.createdAt, b.time, b.researcherId 
FROM (SELECT id, createdAt, 
        UNIX_SECONDS(createdAt)/60 AS minutes 
      FROM datasci.requests
  ) AS a 
JOIN (SELECT time, researcherId, 
        UNIX_SECONDS(time)/60 AS minutes 
      FROM analytics.researchers
  ) AS b 
ON ABS(a.minutes - b.minutes) < 15
```

Would be interesting to hear from you if this anyhow have helped as i didn't have chance to test this

Even if by itself this `transformation` will not help much  - you can apply it to whatever solution you end up with as a further improvement factor